# Superset - Give a user read-only access on a dashboard and edit access on another dashboard

Tags: apache-superset, rbac

I have a question regarding access control on Apache Superset.

Is it possible to grant a specific user read-only access to a dashboard, and edit access to another dashboard?

From what I understand, it's possible to give read-only access to a user (using the Gamma built-in role for instance + custom role with access to data sources / dashboards), or edit access to a user (using a custom role with edit permissions + custom role with access to data sources / dashboards). However, it does not seem feasible to have a mix of the two.

Many thanks!